# PHP 5.6 undefined function xml_parser_create

Tags: php5, xml

I have a new php 5.6 installation and get the following error from my application:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xml_parser_create()
```

But libxml seems to be OK? phpinfo about libxml is:

```
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version   20901
libXML streams  enabled
```

I installed already:

```
    sudo apt-get install php-xml-parser 
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

- Ubuntu 14.04 (yes I know its old but not changeable at the moment).
- Apache 2.4.7
- PHP Package is from ppa:ondrej/php (5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1)

Answer (score 11):

First check installed extensions in php with following command

```
php -m
```

After enter check Do you find follwing xml list?

```
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
```

if not then add following line

```
apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

After doing so, make sure to restart appache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Hope this will help you.